# Maven webapp with tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, tomcat, maven

I'm learning Maven and created a sample WebApp with the following command:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
-DgroupId=org.obliquid \
-DartifactId=test \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp \
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

then ran:

```
mvn package
mvn tomcat:run
```

It works but is using tomcat 6.0.29, how can I change to use tomcat 5.5?

**UPDATE**: I tried @splash suggestion with version 5.5.23 since it seems that the lastest 5.5.33 is not available in the main Maven repo. From the example I've removed catalina-ha, tribes and jasper-jdt and kept the rest (catalina, el-api, jasper, jasper-el, jsp-api, servlet-api, coyote, dbcp). Trying to package:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project yyy: Could not resolve dependencies for project xxx:yyy:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved:     org.apache.tomcat:catalina:jar:5.5.23, org.apache.tomcat:el-api:jar:5.5.23, org.apache.tomcat:jasper:jar:5.5.23, org.apache.tomcat:jasper-el:jar:5.5.23, org.apache.tomcat:jasper-jdt:jar:5.5.23, org.apache.tomcat:jsp-api:jar:5.5.23, org.apache.tomcat:servlet-api:jar:5.5.23, org.apache.tomcat:coyote:jar:5.5.23, org.apache.tomcat:dbcp:jar:5.5.23: Failure to find org.apache.tomcat:catalina:jar:5.5.23 in http://www.mvnsearch.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of mvnsearch has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 1):

I guess this example should answer your question: [Adjust Tomcat Version](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/examples/adjust-embedded-tomcat-version.html)

For Tomcat 5.5 you have to adjust the version (e.g. `5.5.23`) and choose the right dependencies (group `tomcat` instead of `org.apache.tomcat`).

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it doesn't work. The details are too long for a comment, so I've updated my answer.

Comment: oops, I didn't follow this part "(group tomcat instead of org.apache.tomcat)." -> now I try to change all occurrences in my pom.xml

Comment: It got a little better:  [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project yyy: Could not resolve dependencies for project xxx:yyy:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: tomcat:el-api:jar:5.5.23, tomcat:jasper:jar:5.5.23, tomcat:jasper-el:jar:5.5.23, tomcat:jasper-jdt:jar:5.5.23, tomcat:coyote:jar:5.5.23, tomcat:dbcp:jar:5.5.23: Could not find artifact tomcat:el-api:jar:5.5.23 in mvnsearch (http://www.mvnsearch.org/maven2/) -> [Help 1]

Comment: I'm not familiar with Tomcat's package structure, but these artifacts doesn't exists for 5.5 as you can see in the [Maven Central `tomcat` index](http://search.maven.org/#browse|-1142209685) . Just remove them and see what happens.

Comment: I guess it just doesn't work with Tomcat 5.5: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) on project test-webapp: Execution default-cli of goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tomcat.util.IntrospectionUtils.setProperty(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V -- So I give up, I will just install it a local tomcat and try to use tomcat:deploy

Answer (score 0):

Impossible the underlying dependencies of Tomcat aren't available under version 6. [image]

Comment: I've given up on this one, but when I was trying I removed catalina-ha already. Anyway, I also think it's not possible. I've solved using a not Maven controlled tomcat. Also I'm still trying to convince the customer to upgrade their super old installation of Tomcat, probably soon they will :-)